# Opening Microsoft Visual Studio Code from command prompt Windows

Tags: text-editor, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to launch Microsoft Visual Studio Code from the command line in windows? I can't even seem to find the directory for code on my computer. It didn't even ask me where to download it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Navigate to the directory that you want to open and type `code .` to launch VS Code.

Comment: It is just opening vscode but then i have to click the button to open the current folder. It would of be great vscode would open the current folder automatically.

Comment: @Kuncevic you forgot to type the `.` if you type that it will open in the current folder of the cmd prompt.

Comment: I have installed VS code successfully, but when I run code . command sitting on the current project directory it give me error that : code is not recognized as internal or external command... how can I verify is it installed please ?

Comment: @sortednoun are you using git bash? You could try this if you are https://www.seangwright.me/blog/tools/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-from-git-bash-in-windows/.

Comment: It's better to launch "code.cmd" instead of just "code" (which launches code.exe).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134836/visual-studio-code-launched-from-command-line-conflates-the-two-processes/56134837#56134837

Answer (score 8):

As many folks already suggested ways to open code from command prompt using `code .` command. This will only open **Visual Studio Code Stable**  build.  But If you have downloaded **Visual Studio Code Insider** build/version (Which has all latest build/features but unstable version) then you need to follow below instructions in windows :

- Go to Control Panel\System and Security\System. Click on Advanced System Settings
  [image]
- Click on Environment Variables
  [image]
- Under System Variables tab, Click on Edit for Path Variable 
  [image]
- Add a **new** path `C:\Users\tsabu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin` 
  **(or)** 
  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin` based on location at which you have installed vscode insider in your machine.
  [image]

   
  Open a **new** command prompt and type `code-insiders .` to open vscode-insider 
  build/version

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**

```
code your_path your_filename
```

**Long answer:**

Here `your_path` can simply be `.` if you want to use the current directory as your working path. Or `..` for 1 level up, etc.

`code` is the name of the executable of Visual Studio Code (code.exe). If it doesn't launch, perhaps your VSC path hasn't been added to the path environment variable. Run this command to add it:

```
set PATH=";C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin"
```

Of course you'll need to specify a different path if your VSC is installed somewhere else.

[How can you find out the installation path? (click for screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5DDA.png) Go to "Start" menu, type in "Visual Studio Code", right click on the found program, "Properties", check "Target". Now you'll see!

Answer (score 1):

It may come already added to your path when installed. Try using `code <filename>` in your command line. If it's not you can add the command line script's directory to your path. The command line script's directory is downloaded by default in the following location

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Code\bin
```

Comment: ... Did you just answer your own question as if you were someone else?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. There was a blog post about it earlier last year I think and it said to ask the question as if you didn't know the answer. You can still answer if you can get it working in git bash I can't seem to figure that out right now.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline: This is perfectly cromulent SO etiquette :)

Answer (score 0):

Point your command prompt to the specific folder that has the file that you want to open. Let's say you want to open the file titled main.scss. Simply run this command:

```
start code main.scss
```

If Visual Studio Code is already open, you can simply do:

```
code main.scss
```